# X access mirror modifier behaving like Z access mirror?

Tags: modeling, mirror

Something bizarre seems to be happening where applying the X access mirror modifier mirrors on the Z access and the Z access modifier flips it over the X.

You can see in the photo below that X is selected to mirror, but it's not mirroring on the X. It's flipping on the Z instead.

[image: Problem]

I tried doing [these cursor fixing steps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right), although it seems like it might be a different problem, since it don't work.

What went wrong? How do I fix it? This is 2.8 Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must apply the transforms, or avoid the rotation in object mode.
See here:
[Problem creating mirror in X, Y axes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131252/problem-creating-mirror-in-x-y-axes/131257#131257)

Comment: `CTRL+a` then select `rotate and scale`.